# How to expose a service to get the content of a component?

Tags: rest, restfulapi

The requirement is that there is a outside application which will get the content maintained in CMS. We want to expose a RESTful HTTP service in CDA for it to consume. Our CDA is based on DXA1.4.1 (Java)

Comment: Is this pre Web 8? Because with Web 8 you already have Content Service and you can definitely use it without having to create something from Scratch :)

Comment: is there any example or documents? thanks

Comment: is it content delivery API or OData service? I just want to get the content of a component by its name. is there an example on how to do that?

Comment: On a dxa page you can also append ?format=json to it to retrieve the full data model. Maybe that's enough?

Answer (score 1):

You could put a .Net WebService like WebApi 2 or ServiceStack in front of a Core Service app to get the Component XML.  Also, note that the native CoreService xml methods do not expose the Component Metadata.  As far as looking up items by name, OOTB Tridion has the internal Solr search engine - but I'd probably look @ persisting the Component Name, URI, and any other data to another data store (NoSql, Redis, ElasticSearch, etc) and then having your code get the URI for an item, then use CoreService to get the XML.

If you're looking for an approach on the Content Delivery side, then I would suggest publishing JSON / XML to the Broker DB.  If you want to build your own DSL for content-consumption, then you might want to take a look at a Tridion Custom Deployer a colleague wrote that deploys to MongoDB (JSON) and Amazon S3 (Binaries).  The Tridion 2013 source is here:  https://github.com/aeyckerman/tridion-camel-extension

Comment: I think the CoreService is in CMS side. but I'm looking for the approach in CDA side. i'm very new in Tridion CMS, please correct me in case of any mistakes

Comment: I edited my answer to include more ideas about CDA.